# Force existing website to print mobile version

Tags: css, web, bootstrap-4

Couple constraints.

1. I'm working with Sharepoint 2013, which occasionally messes stuff up. Hopefully not relevant.
2. I can't change the viewport meta tag for the site.
3. The website is a very large existing site that I did not create, I'm just creating a new print-css for it that is meant to utilize the tablet view for all pages without you know, recreating it from scratch.
4. Bootstrap version 4 is used fairly extensively.

So in this context, I'm trying to find a way to force a page to utilize the same CSS as a device with a view width of say, 800px would see, when it is printing.

I'm getting pretty close to pegging this one as simply impossible as I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to improvise a solution, and found zero other cases via google where someone had this particular issue.

Ideally, I want to do this via the print CSS, but I'm pretty open to any wacky solution at this point as long as it only affects the print view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply apply the same media queries for a print view as you would for a screen size of `800px`. (I'm assuming in my example that you mean screens *up* to this width)

The following will set a red `color` for both smaller screens and print views, while leaving larger screens unmodified.

```css
@media only print, only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .red {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Red Text</div>
```